# Where's the implementation of a class extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm missing something simple - clearly. When I add an objective C class extension, it only creates a .h file -- where am I supposed to do the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class extension does what it says;  it extends the declaration of a class.   Unlike categories, class extensions can add `@property` declarations that will be automatically synthesized when the `@implementation` of the class is compiled.

The only requirement is that all class extension declarations are either declared or `#import`ed prior to the compilation of the `@implementation`.

I.e. the class's `@implementation` *is the implementation of the extension*.

Comment: I'm still a tiny bit confused. Say I extend NSObject - and add a property someProperty - could I then initialize SomeArray from any NSObject where I have imported the extension via self.someArray?

If I wanted to have a method doSomethingToTheProperty - would I have to define that method in every implementation where I import the extension? Or, alternatively, could I use the extension to add properties and then a category to do methods on those properties (assuming I import the extension). I might be making things more confusing then they are..

Comment: @JoshDG because you did not provide NSObject's implementation, you cannot extend it using a class extension. you might consider a subclass as an alternative.

Comment: Class extensions are used on a class that you implement to divide the class's interface into multiple pieces. They aren't useful on classes that you did not implement.